# How do I write a method to validate if the username created is too short?

Tags: javascript, forms, validation

I have the following html code:

```
<div class="result hide" id="userNameTooShort"><span class="error">Your username needs to be six characters long.</span></div>
```

I want this to display when a user types less than 6 characters in the username input field. The hide class displays none if it is valid.

Here is the input field I created in javascript:

```
createFieldObjects: function(){
    unField = new forms.InputField("tUserName", /^(?=.*[a-zA-Z\d])(\w|[\.\@\-\?\,\&\''\/\_\""]){6,}$/);
},
```

How do I write the javascript to display the error message when the user types less than 6 characters?

Comment: I know several people whose first and last names together are less than 6 characters. They can get pretty cranky if you tell them that their name isn't valid, so exercise some caution here, and think about why you need so many characters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a prototype/pseudocode way:

```
if $('tUserName').value.length < 6
  (set the div to display)
```